# Problema ao utilizar push no array JS

Tags: javascript, array

Estou inserindo algumas datas formatadas em um *array*. Quando seleciono por dia, o formato precisa ser *"DD/MM"*, porém eu recebo da *API* *"MM/DD"*, nesse caso eu faço a inversão após o *push* no array, devido a outras regras.

O problema ocorre somente quando é selecionado a data *02/29* até *01/03*.
O *array*, de alguma forma, acho que se perde e insere duas vezes a data *"01/03"*.

**Dados:**

```
[
  {pass_date_time: "03/01", name: "objeto 1" },
  {pass_date_time: "02/29", name: "objeto 2" },
  {pass_date_time: "03/01", name: "objeto 3" },
  {pass_date_time: "03/01", name: "objeto 4" }
]
```

**Código:**

```
      data.forEach(element => {

        if (!Array.includes(element.pass_date_time)) {

          Array.push(element.pass_date_time;

        }
      });

     Array.sort();
```

O resultado esperado: `Array: ["01/03","02/29"]`
Resultado obtido: `Array: ["01/03","01/03"]`

[image: Primeio loop do foreach]

[image: Segundo loop]

Comment: isso é no backend? existem várias formas de resolver o seu problema mas primeiro preciso saber o que você realmente quer, sua pergunta não foi muito clara

Comment: Desculpe por não me expressar bem, isso é no frontend, onde eu recebo esse objeto "DATA" de uma API, o que eu preciso é armazenar as datas no "ARRAY"  na ordem correta dos dias dos meses.

Comment: entendi vou colocar minha resposta que eu acho que entendi o que você quer fazer...

Comment: Revertido.O escopo da pergunta não pode ser modificado depois de receber respostas, pois se o fizer invalida as mesmas. Se tem outra dúvida crie uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas com o código:

- Há um erro de sintaxe na linha `Array.push(element.pass_date_time;`
- Você está utilizando um tipo nativo do Javascript o [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) como se fosse uma variável.

  Para resolver o erro de sintaxe basta  colocar o `)` concluindo a sentença.

  Quanto ao problema da nomenclatura basta criar um array para receber o resultado e fazer o uso de nomes mais descritivos em seu código.

```js
//Cria o array contendo os dados.
let dados = [{
    pass_date_time: "03/01",
    name: "objeto 1"
  },
  {
    pass_date_time: "02/29",
    name: "objeto 2"
  },
  {
    pass_date_time: "03/01",
    name: "objeto 3"
  },
  {
    pass_date_time: "03/01",
    name: "objeto 4"
  }
]

//Cria o array que irá receber os resultados.
let resultado = [];

//Para cada elemento em dados...
dados.forEach(elemento => {
  //Verifica se ja há um mesmo resultado. 
  if (!resultado.includes(elemento.pass_date_time)) {
    //Se não houver adiciona o elemeto ao resultado.
    resultado.push(elemento.pass_date_time);
  }
});

resultado.sort(); //Oredena o resultado.
console.log(resultado); //Imprime o resultado.
```

Comment: Olá Augusto, fiz as devidas correções, porém continuo com o mesmo retorno, editei a pergunta com o código atualizado.

Comment: Clica no executar e veja o resultado. https://imgur.com/mcsFmY2

Comment: Certo, tenho esse resultado no array mas as posições "dentro" dele  mudam: segue imagem com o resultado https://imgur.com/0A4BzsX

Comment: As posições não são as que espera porque você esta trabalhando com strings e não com datas. O que já é outra coisa que envolve converter as string em datas para então ordená-las

Comment: Certo, ai que fica a questão, com qualquer outra data, não ocorre esse problema, você saberia como resolve-lo?

Comment: É que lhe falei converta as strings em datas para então ordená-las. Pois string são ordenada com base no primeiro caractere, se forem iguais o critério passa ser o segundo e assim por diante. Já as datas são ordenadas conforme o calendário.

Answer (score 1):

você pode utilizar a biblioteca do momentjs que é ótima nesses casos e para resolver o seu array pode fazer o seguinte:
link da biblioteca: https://momentjs.com/

```
const newData = data.map(index => {
  return moment(index.pass_date_time).format("DD/MM");
});
```

na constante newData receberá um novo array com os valores das datas já convertidos depois é só extrai-los. espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Essa parte da conversão da data eu utilizo o moment, realmente é muito bom. A questão é que o problema está somente no Push do Array, onde ele deveria inserir as duas datas, sendo elas "29/02" e "01/03", porém ele insere duas vezes o "01/03".

Comment: o array ja tem algum index dentro dele?

Comment: Não, eu estou criando ele vazio, pois depende da situação eu utilizo com outros tipos de datas.

Comment: então, este caso seria a melhor situação para você do que o forEach pois ele devolve um novo array, eu só guardei em uma nova variável para extrair você pode criar outras variáveis tipo assim:
`const hourOne = newData[0];
const hourTwo = newData[1];`

lembrando que isso é apenas um método

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com algumas imagens, ve se ajuda.